# What is the correct way to embed (string) data in element attibute?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I would like to send data from the server to the client, where javascript code can access the data. This is basically a string message, what I would like to embed in my custom attribute like this:

```
 <div my-message="here is my custom data">
```

After short testing I recognized the message itself can contain special char like " so the html will be incorrect after embedding.

What is the correct way to (encode?) the string data? (server side is ASP MVC)

Is there any javascript support to decode the string? Obviously say base64 can do it, but it sounds a bit weird, and also I would not like reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: If you plan on using attributes, [please prefix them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) with `data-` for example: `data-my-message`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For server side:

### Razor

```
<div data-my-message="@("your string with \" goes here")">
```

Or if you hold the string in the Model

```
<div data-my-message="@Model.Message">
```

### ASPX

```
<div data-my-message="<%: "your string with \" goes here" %>">
```

Razor's `@()` or ASPX's `<%: %>` will encode it correctly.

BTW If you want to embed your string directly in the view you can escape the `"` with `\"`

## For client side:

You can read it easily with jQuery

```
$(selector).data("my-message")
```

or plain javascript

```
document.querySelector(selector).dataset.myMessage
```

Also you should prefix your custom attributes with `data-` as @Erik Philips says in the comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` for encoding. And for decoding the functions `decodeURI` and `decodeURIComponents`.

You can look them up for example here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send arbitary data (i.e. arrays, objects, etc.) then I use the following:

- use a data-foo attribute on the tag
- json-encode the data
- Use single quotes around the attribute value (JSON uses double quotes for strings)
- Replace any single-quotes in the json-encoded string with the corresponding thml entity (&#8217)

Something like (I did it in PHP so the .net syntact might be slightly wrong

```
<% Dim Serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer %>
<div data-foo='<%=Serializer.Serialize(MyData).Replace("'", "&#8217") %>'>Some content</div>
```

Where the data to use is in the variable MyData

Has the advantage that when you get out the data you get an object back automatically (at least, with jQuery but I would imagine with plain js too - if not then it's easy to recreate the object)

**Update**
Following the comment about double quotes, if your data is just a string then you should replace double quotes buy their html entity too.  Or ensure you json-deode.  It's not automatically recognised as json data and decoded if it's just a string.  PHP (where I have used this more) encopdes double quotes in the string as `\"`.  I have a memnory that in vb.net you need to change `Serializer.Serialize(MyData).Replace("'", "&#8217")` to `Serializer.Serialize(MyData).Replace("\", "\\").Replace("'", "&#8217")` becuase of how it handles quotes. If the data is an object then it is automatically json-decoded when you get it out and alls is OK.  if the data is just a string then don't need to json-encode maybe - just change at least one of the type of quotes (either single or double quotes) to html entities and use that quote type around the attribute.

As long as you get the quoting right it handles html in the data fine: see http://jsfiddle.net/ctueo7sr/ for a simple string example and http://jsfiddle.net/aLaLnhp2/1/ for an object example

Comment: This will break when the JSON contains double quotes (`"`) and HTML entities or text that looks like entities.

Comment: Really.  Double quotes?  I would have expected the JSON-ecoder to escape them automatically.  If not then add a .Replace("\", "\\") to the decode.

Comment: As long as you get the quotes right, it copes with html in the atrtribute fine.  See http://jsfiddle.net/ctueo7sr/